# Обновление обьектов через setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({ temperature: 1, scale: "c" });
```

Задаю state таким образом, пытаюсь засетать новый обьект:

```js
const handleCelsiusChange = (temperature) => {
    setState({ temperature, scale: "c" });
  };
```

Вовзращается `[object, Object]`, как правильно сетать обьекты через этот хук?

Comment: Где именно у вас появляется [object, Object]?

Answer (score 0):

Универсальное решение для добавление/обновление значений

```js
const handleCelsiusChange = (key, value) => {
    setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        [key]: value,
      };
    });
  };
```

а дальше в коде

```js
handleCelsiusChange("temperature", 1);
```

при этом значение для `scale` остается из дефолтного определения

**UPD** мысль из комментария

```js
const handleCelsiusChange = (temperature_value) => {
    setState({ temperature: temperature_value, scale: "c" });
  };
```

Comment: а в случае если я хочу изменить значения для всех ключей всё равно нельзя просто переписать обьект? так как у меня записано?

Comment: Можно, но только пишите правильно и понимайте, что вы передаете в переменной `temprature` когда вызываете `setState`

Comment: @MaksShevchenko обновил ответ